# How do I know if a game was updated?

Tags: xbox-one

I like to read release notes of game patches. Is there a way to be notified or to know when a game was updated?

Comment: Following a game's official Twitter feed has honestly been the best way IMO to find out when patches happen. *Smite* is a good example of a game that tweets about patches, posts them online, and recently started adding a button to the game's main menu that launches IE and goes to the patch notes on their site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Games that have been recently updated *should* get a little white corner added to their tile in My Games and Apps, with a black asterisk on top. This applies to games that have been updated, or need an update.

[image: update icons]

However, in my experience it does not show up on Pins, and sometimes it doesn't show up at all. Not sure if that's a bug, or if the system periodically pings to check for game updates, and I just opened the game before it pinged, but it happens once in a while that a game without the flagged tile needs an update when I open it.

For release notes specifically, you have to rely on the developers of each game to either post them in-game, or on the web.